# angular jsonp is not giving any response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http, angular-httpclient

i am hitting third party library from angular js. They sent response inside callback function . i am using http Jsonp method to try to get that response.i didn't get any response.

```
getActiveProduct: function() {
              var deferred = $q.defer();  
              var url ="myserver/getproject.json"
              $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)
             $http.jsonp(url, {
                  jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',
                  data:''
              }).then(function(data){
                  deferred.resolve(data.data);
              },function(error){
                  console.log(error);
                    return deferred.reject(err);
                });
              return deferred.promise;
            }
```

below i mentioned beckend response

```
projectInstance.jsonpCallback("getActiveProduct",{"totalRecords":null,"projectSnapShot":[{"projectId":"333333","projectNumber":"123456","projectStatus":"Active"}]})
```

how to get this response in my application.which angular http method i need to use?

Comment: `var url ="myserver/getproject.json"` doesnt sound like a valide JSONP endpoint, is it? Why do you want to use JSONP?

Comment: i mentioned sample url .my endpoint response i attached above. can you help me how to fetch these callback response